# VBO is not being updated using QGLBuffer

Tags: qt, opengl

I am creating an application using OpenGL that draws some quad planes in a tridimensional space. Everything was working fine until I start to set different vertices coordinates for each plane. Now, when I create a plane with new coordinates, it is drawn like it was a previous created plane. In other words, its new coordinates are note being used.

I am using OpenGL with Qt library.

```
void Plane::initBuffers()
{
    mVertexVBO.create(); //QGLBuffer
    mIndexVBO.create();  //QGLBuffer

    mVertexVBO.bind();
    mIndexVBO.bind();

    mVertexVBO.setUsagePattern(QGLBuffer::StaticDraw);
    mIndexVBO.setUsagePattern(QGLBuffer::StaticDraw);

    /* mVertices and mIndices are a QVarLengthArray object */
    Vertex* aVerts = mVertices.data();
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    {
        qDebug() << aVerts[i].x << " " << aVerts[i].y << " " << aVerts[i].z;
    }
    qDebug() << " --- ";

    mVertexVBO.allocate(mVertices.data(), sizeof(Vertex)*4);
    mIndexVBO.allocate(mIndices.data(), sizeof(GLuint)*6);
}
```

I created 2 planes. Each one of them is created by default with the following coordinates:

```
-1   -1  0 
-1   1   0 
1    1   0 
1   -1   0
```

I changed the coordinates of the first plane to

```
1   0   0 
0   0   0 
0   0   1 
1   0   1
```

However, those planes are draw exactly the same. The are only in different places because I've change their model matrix. The QVarLengthArray is beign correctly updated (the above code execution showed me that).

Somebody knows what am I missing?

Comment: Have you considered *not* using `QGLBuffer`? It seems to be missing vital APIs, like a `bind` function that actually takes a location that the buffer object should be bound to. Also, what type parameters do you use when creating these objects?

Comment: Yes. This is my B plan. But I wouldn't like to do so, because QGLBuffer offers some pratical advantages (it is just easier to deal with). To create the QGLBuffer objects I've passed a Qt parameter to determine the buffer type (vertex, index...). According to Qt docs, the parameters you've mentioned are treated internally to QGLBuffer. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved! Actually, there wasn't a problem related to VBOs... I just was not updating normals and my plane was (as expected) completely dark (invisible). Hopefully, nobody lost any time thinking in this issue... Sorry! =D